# update string as plural once it is more than 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following span, I want to use the method pluralize, till there is items equal to 1, I want to display 1 item, at the moment it is by default 0 items, If something gets added it says 1 items

```
<span id="cartitems">
<%=@size%>
items
</span>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use Rails I18n and write something like:

`I18n.t('items', count: @size)`

and then in your `config/locales/en.yml` file:

```
en:
  items:
    zero: "no items"
    one: "one item"
    other: "%{count} items"
```

Comment: It gives me this translation **missing: en.items**

Comment: @Suraj, `items` key is to be added under `en` in your `config/locales/en.yml`.

Comment: I already did that like this there

`items:
     zero: no items
     one: one item
     other: %{count} items`

probably missing something.

Comment: Look at @vee suggestion and if have just created the en.yml file restart your server.

Comment: Can not load translation ..

found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 26 column 12>


THIS

Comment: look at how I changed the answer

Answer (score 6):

Do this instead

```
<%= pluralize(@size, 'item') %>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

How about you use [pluralize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/pluralize)

```
<%= pluralize @size, 'item' %>
```

Comment: thanks it works, by default it shows me 0 items though and once I delete an item from cart, the "item" string disappears

Comment: Use I18n.t like in @coorase's answer instead.

Comment: It gives me this translation missing: en.items